# react setState external behavior

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Is it acceptable to operate on the state when setting the next state, within the dispatchAction? Or is it preferable to use reducer?

```
  const Person = { freeze: () => {} };

  const nextPerson = new Person();

  setPerson((prevPerson) => {
    prevPerson.freeze();
    // or
    handleMe(prevPerson)

    return nextPerson;
  });
```

Comment: See https://redux.js.org/faq/organizing-state#organizing-state-only-redux-state

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.